# How to remove the most recently added control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I Intended to display an PictureBox in my form when the mouse hovered over another control. I then wanted to use a separate event for when the mouse left the control. This event would remove the displayed PictureBox from controls. However, because my events are private subs, I can't directly access the name of the control in the latter event. A solution to this would be a method that removes the most recently added control. If no such method exists, or there is an alternative way of approaching this problem, any help would be appreciated.

I tried simply using Controls.Remove(), but this requires a parameter. The name of the control as a string did not work either, as the parameter must be a control itself.

```
Private Sub Tile_MouseEnter(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim CloseUpPic As New PictureBox With {Properties}
    CloseUpPic.Image = Sender.Image
    Controls.Add(CloseUpPic)

    Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub Tile_MouseLeave(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Me.Controls.Remove()

End Sub
```

The program won't compile due to .Remove() needing a parameter

I expected for the Control to be created and displayed when the mouse entered the tile, and to cease to exist when the mouse left the tile.

Comment: Removing won't dispose the control.  `If Me.Controls.Count > 0 Then Me.Controls(Me.Controls.Count - 1).Dispose() End If`

Comment: Could you use .Visible True, False and set the properties as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code to solve my issue:

```
            For Each Closeup In Controls.OfType(Of CloseUp)

                Controls.Remove(Closeup)

            Next
```

I created a new class of my own called Closeup, that inherits PictureBox. I then looped through each Closeup in controls (There was only one but this code works for multiple controls), and removed them.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, controls have [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2) property which allows you to store whatever you like.  In this case, you can store a reference to the newly created PictureBox.  Furthermore, the "Sender" parameter tells you which control was the source of the event.  You can cast sender to a control, then store the reference.  Then, in the leave event, you can cast sender to a control, cast the .Tag to a control, and finally remove it:

```
Private Sub Tile_MouseEnter(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(Sender, Control)

    Dim CloseUpPic As New PictureBox With {Properties}
    CloseUpPic.Image = Sender.Image
    Controls.Add(CloseUpPic)

    ctl.Tag = CloseUpPic

    Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub Tile_MouseLeave(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(Sender, Control)
    Dim ctlToRemove As Control = DirectCast(ctl.Tag, Control)
    Me.Controls.Remove(ctlToRemove)
End Sub
```